# Android how to create runtime thumbnail

Tags: android

I have a large sized image. At runtime, I want to read the image from storage and scale it so that its weight and size gets reduced and I can use it as a thumbnail. When a user clicks on the thumbnail, I want to display the full-sized image.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

My Solution

```
byte[] imageData = null;

        try     
        {

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            imageData = baos.toByteArray();

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

        }
```

Comment: My files were to large, so I had to use sub sampling in the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);` step.  See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) for more detail about sub sampling.

Comment: It's better to use Android's `ThumbnailUils` class like the answer below.

Comment: @afollestad Not really, this approach is the correct one. Using ThumbnailUtils is only a good idea when you are 100% sure you are working with small files.

Comment: This solution has a BIG bug: imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, ...); you will lose the first imageBitmap WITHOUT RECYCLING IT! Sooner or later it will bring to an OutOfMemoryError...

Comment: if (!imageBitmap.isRecycled()) imageBitmap.recycle();

Comment: This solution nonetheless loads the whole Bitmap into the memory and then scales it.

Comment: This solution does not preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 136):

Try this

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

This Utility is available from API_LEVEl 8. [[Source]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)

Comment: Using this code you are actually loading in memory a copy of the large bitmap, so this is not a good way of managing big images.

Comment: The correct way to go is decoding a downsampled version of the file. Other answers offer this approach. Also the official docs explain the process well: https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html . Since this one is the most voted answer (due its simplicity), i just wanted to warn everyone that this is not the best way.

Comment: How I can apply this to a drawable resource?

Comment: Does this solution keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Whats the import for this?

Answer (score 15):

The best solution I found is the following. Compared with the other solutions this one does not need to load the full image for creating a thumbnail, so it is more efficient!
**Its limit is that you can not have a thumbnail with exact width and height** but the solution as near as possible.

```
File file = ...; // the image file

Options bitmapOptions = new Options();
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // obtain the size of the image, without loading it in memory
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

// find the best scaling factor for the desired dimensions
int desiredWidth = 400;
int desiredHeight = 300;
float widthScale = (float)bitmapOptions.outWidth/desiredWidth;
float heightScale = (float)bitmapOptions.outHeight/desiredHeight;
float scale = Math.min(widthScale, heightScale);

int sampleSize = 1;
while (sampleSize < scale) {
    sampleSize *= 2;
}
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize; // this value must be a power of 2,
                                         // this is why you can not have an image scaled as you would like
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // now we want to load the image

// Let's load just the part of the image necessary for creating the thumbnail, not the whole image
Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

// Save the thumbnail
File thumbnailFile = ...;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(thumbnailFile);
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

// Use the thumbail on an ImageView or recycle it!
thumbnail.recycle();
```

Comment: This is best for low memory devices

Comment: Thank you. It has solved problem with out of memory exception.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more complete solution to scaling down a Bitmap to thumbnail size.  It expands on the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap solution by maintaining the aspect ratio of the images and also padding them to the same width so that they look good in a ListView.

Also, it would be best to do this scaling once and store the resulting Bitmap as a blob in your Sqlite database.  I have included a snippet on how to convert the Bitmap to a byte array for this purpose.

```
public static final int THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 48;
public static final int THUMBNAIL_WIDTH = 66;

imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mImageData, 0, mImageData.length);
Float width  = new Float(imageBitmap.getWidth());
Float height = new Float(imageBitmap.getHeight());
Float ratio = width/height;
imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT*ratio), THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, false);

int padding = (THUMBNAIL_WIDTH - imageBitmap.getWidth())/2;
imageView.setPadding(padding, 0, padding, 0);
imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);



ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you switched arguments order for `THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT` and `THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT` for `createScaledBitmap`?

Answer (score 6):

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(...)` to get your `Bitmap` object and set it to an `ImageView` with `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`.

On the `ImageView` set the layout dimensions to something small, eg:

```
android:layout_width="66dip" android:layout_height="48dip"
```

Add an `onClickListener` to the `ImageView` and launch a new activity, where you display the image in full size with

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or specify some larger size.

Comment: When having multiple images you should consider scaling it down to the thumb size beforehand. otherwise that could slow down the performance when moving the set.

Comment: Indeed, and to do that you would use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);

Comment: dones following method also reduce the weight of the image ?
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false)

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Creates a centered bitmap of the desired size.
 *
 * @param source original bitmap source
 * @param width targeted width
 * @param height targeted height
 * @param options options used during thumbnail extraction
 */
public static Bitmap extractThumbnail(
        Bitmap source, int width, int height, int options) {
    if (source == null) {
        return null;
    }

    float scale;
    if (source.getWidth() < source.getHeight()) {
        scale = width / (float) source.getWidth();
    } else {
        scale = height / (float) source.getHeight();
    }
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    Bitmap thumbnail = transform(matrix, source, width, height,
            OPTIONS_SCALE_UP | options);
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: where is transform(matrix, source, width, height,
            OPTIONS_SCALE_UP | options) Method

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/kontalk/source/browse/src/org/kontalk/xmpp/util/ThumbnailUtils.java?repo=androidclient&name=xmpp&r=f879e85d21d6e0a8a6f736ebe90c03e851b51436

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to do this

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath),200,200)
```

**Syntax**

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(Bitmap source,int width,int height)
```

**OR**

> use Picasso dependancy
>
> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png")
    .resize(50, 50)
    .into(imageView2);
```

Reference [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want high quality result, so use [RapidDecoder][1] library. It is simple as follow:

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;
...
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDecoder.from(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
                             .scale(width, height)
                             .useBuiltInDecoder(true)
                             .decode();
```

Don't forget to use builtin decoder if you want to scale down less than 50% and a HQ result.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the solution presented in https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html (without using of external libraries) with some changes by me to make its functionality better and more practical.

Some notes about this solution:

1. It is assumed that you want to **keep the aspect ratio**. In other words:

   **`finalWidth / finalHeight == sourceBitmap.getWidth() / sourceBitmap.getWidth()`** <sub>(Regardless of casting and rounding issues)</sub>
2. It is assumed that you have two values (`maxWidth` & `maxHeight`) that **you want *any of* the dimensions of your final bitmap doesn't exceed its corresponding value**. In other words:

   **`finalWidth <= maxWidth && finalHeight <= maxHeight`**

   <sup>So `minRatio` has been placed as the basis of calculations (See the implementation). *UNLIKE the basic solution that has placed `maxRatio` as the basis of calculations in actual*. Also, the calculation of `inSampleSize` has been so much better (more logic, brief and efficient).</sup>
3. It is assumed that **you want to (at least) one of the final dimensions has *exactly* the value of its corresponding maxValue** <sub>(each one was possible, by considering the above assumptions)</sub>. In other words:

   **`finalWidth == maxWidth || finalHeight == maxHeight`**

   The final additional step in compare to the basic solution (`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...)`) is for this "*exactly*" constraint. *The very important note is **you shouldn't take this step at first** (like [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934983/5318303)), because of its significant consumption of memory in case of huge images!*
4. It is for decoding a `file`. You can change it like the basic solution to decode a `resource` (or everything that `BitmapFactory` supports).

The implementation:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String pathName, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

    final float wRatio_inv = (float) options.outWidth / maxWidth,
          hRatio_inv = (float) options.outHeight / maxHeight; // Working with inverse ratios is more comfortable
    final int finalW, finalH, minRatio_inv /* = max{Ratio_inv} */;

    if (wRatio_inv > hRatio_inv) {
        minRatio_inv = (int) wRatio_inv;
        finalW = maxWidth;
        finalH = Math.round(options.outHeight / wRatio_inv);
    } else {
        minRatio_inv = (int) hRatio_inv;
        finalH = maxHeight;
        finalW = Math.round(options.outWidth / hRatio_inv);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = pow2Ceil(minRatio_inv); // pow2Ceil: A utility function that comes later
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options),
          finalW, finalH, true);
}

/**
 * @return the largest power of 2 that is smaller than or equal to number. 
 * WARNING: return {0b1000000...000} for ZERO input.
 */
public static int pow2Ceil(int number) {
    return 1 << -(Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(number) + 1); // is equivalent to:
    // return Integer.rotateRight(1, Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(number) + 1);
}
```

---

Sample Usage, in case of you have an `imageView` with a determined value for `layout_width` (`match_parent` or a explicit value) and a indeterminate value for `layout_height` (`wrap_content`) and instead a determined value for `maxHeight`:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmap(filePath, 
        imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getMaxHeight()));
```