# scrolling issues in gridview when displaying a large number of images in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-image, android-gridview

I want to display a large number of images(say 500).i am currently displaying them in a scrollable grid layout by lazyloading images(very similar to fedor's lazylist). but i am having issues while scrolling the grid. when i scroll the grid, the views get refreshed and the actual images are reloaded. so, even the images that were displayed earlier are refetched from SD card. this causes a very slow UI. is there any solutions for this.(i.e is there a way to tell the grid view not to refesh views on scrolling).

or

is there any other better way to display large number of images.

Comment: Are you loading big images ? If yes, maybe an optimisation would be to compute thumbnails and use those ones.

Comment: yeah i am using big images. how do i compute the thumbnails of big images and how to get the big original image when i check on the thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thumbnails would speed things up a bit.
Check out: [Android how to create runtime thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577221/android-how-to-create-runtime-thumbnail)

Comment: the problem is not having small images. even if i make the images small, since i am using lazyloading of images, the threads are started which will load the images. this takes up memory and when the scrolling stops i dont get the images quickly. any way to resolve that