# 2 issues with android bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a ListView, with about 50 rows. Each item has an image. Sometimes, the images are downloaded, but sometimes, I just show a specific image from app resources.

Issues:

1. Sometimes I just show about 20 images from resources for my items
   that all of the are the same image .it means I just show an image
   for 20 rows that all the same.  is it loading a bitmap an take the
   amount of ram for each item ? or it just load an image and show it
   for other items ?
2. The imageview's size for each item is 100*70 dp . so I want to do
   something , like re sizing or reducing the image dp before I bitmap
   them and show them in my app, so I can reduce the amount of ram they
   takes . Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Showing same image multiple times

If you set all the image as same Drawable (variable), you got from resources, Only 1 bitmap Drawable resides in RAM. Also, ListView recycles its rows, it does not really create 20 rows with all 20 Bitmaps loaded in RAM.

> Setting DPI of images

BitmapDrawable class can automatically decide DPI for rendering, that's why it asks for Resources in its [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources%29). Or you can call [`setTargetDensity(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTargetDensity%28int%29) later. *NOTE: Changing DPI is not exactly same thing as Scaling an Image.*

> Loading scaled down images

This will definitely save RAM, Read [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2577221/1531054) on how to load scaled down images.