# Android: Take a thumbnail image using the Camera API

Tags: android, camera

Is it possible to take a thumbnail photo using the camera? I see methods like getJpegThumbnailQuality but I don't see anything for taking the actual thumbnail. I must do this using the Camera API and not using an Intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any means, Camera itself will not directly produce a Bitmap of thumbnail size. Most devices have limited set of picture resolutions for camera. However you can  [create another scaled down bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934983/1531054) from the picture camera provides you.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the getJpegThumbnailQuality when you end up creating your own thumbnail and setting the quality during creation?

Comment: @AndroidDev Jpeg format supports inclusion of a lot of metadata about the image, thumbnail as well.

Comment: Actually, what I think you meant to say is that jpgs can contain embedded thumbnails and the getJpegThumbnailQuality along with other thumbnail APIs are used to read information about those thumbnails. Whether a camera supports a thumbnail or not probably can only be determined from the getJpegThumbnailSize method, which I assume returns zero for height and width if the camera does not support automatic thumbnail embedding.

Comment: @AndroidDev yes, the thumbnail ( it may or may not put, as per hardware) which will be stored in EXIF data of jpeg.