# how to save captured image with custom size in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-camera, android-bitmap, android-capture

in my application i can open the camera and take a picture. The picture is stored in a full size of 2448x3264 pixels on the sd-card. how can i configure this in my application, to save the picture in a size of 90x90 pixels and not in 2448x3264 pixel?

to open the camera and capture a image i use following methods:

```
/*
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create " + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

/*              
                try {
                    decodeUri(this, fileUri, 90, 90);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/

                // successfully captured the image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Picture successfully captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } 
    }   

public static Bitmap decodeUri(Context c, Uri uri, final int requiredWidth, final int requiredHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o);

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;

        while(true) {
            if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredWidth || height_tmp / 2 < requiredHeight)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o2);
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }
```

i hope that s.o. can help me with this. i am trying to load the captured images into a little imageview, look like [that](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/assets/list_view/list-view-example-1-95973c43c6eed64af57c7e050981966b.jpg). thanks in advance

Comment: Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, height, width, true);

Comment: sirFrankenstine, thank you for your help. see my answer below

Comment: can no one help me with this? what i want it only a saved thumbnail of the captured image, to use that in a custom listview.

Comment: can you not create a ScaledBitmap after capturing the initial image?

Comment: unfortunately no. because i dont know where and how to save it as bitmap. the saved images on the sd-card are in .jpg format. it is possible to resize it as in thumbnail format before saving it on sd-card?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot control the picture size when you use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent. You can achieve this if you implement your ["custom camera"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) (and there are plenty of working samples on Internet), including *[mine](https://github.com/alexcohn/JBcamera)*.

The byte array received in `onPictureTaken()` is a Jpeg buffer. Look at this Java package for image manipulation: http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/ (there is an Android port [on GitHub](http://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil)). There are very powerful and efficient methods to scale down Jpeg, without decoding it into Bitmap and back.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'm giving a method which will take the saved path on SDCard of taken picture and will return the required size image as Bitmap. Now what you have to do is just pass image path on SDCard and get the resized image.

```
private Bitmap processTakenPicture(String fullPath) {

    int targetW = 90; //your required width
    int targetH = 90; //your required height

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath, bmOptions);

    int scaleFactor = 1;
    scaleFactor = calculateInSampleSize(bmOptions, targetW, targetH);

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor * 2;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath, bmOptions);

    return bitmap;
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {

    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: thank u hamid, but i want to save it in the custom size at the beginning. that is what i want. is there an option to make this? i am using a simplecursor adapter to load the informations in the custom listview. that means, i have to give a resource id (for example: R.id.image)

Answer (score 0):

After you had read the original image, you can use:

```
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, width, height, true);
```

Comment: thank u mina for your help. i want to save it in the custom size. see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577221/android-how-to-create-runtime-thumbnail) wherre a guy has the same problem. He uses the following.

```
    Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```