# Android ImageView- shall I reduce Image Size

Tags: android, imageview

In the android app that I am building, the users can upload their profile pictures. These picture would then go into a "grid view". In my case the column width of grid view is lesser than the image size.

So in order to make it fit, would I have to reduce the image size at the backend server before uploading it into the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) to create thumbnail of the image in the Android code itself. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294235/1306419) answer on [Android how to create runtime thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577221/android-how-to-create-runtime-thumbnail) for more.