# ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter with thumnails

Tags: android

i am displaying images with slide show .. i want to add thumbnails to it.
below i want as thumnail as how many images and which specific image it is displaying.
i went through many sites but dint find anything helpful

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    int[] GalImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.chokkanatha1,
        R.drawable.chokkanatha2,
        R.drawable.chokkanatha3,
        R.drawable.chokkanatha4,
        R.drawable.chokkanatha5,
        R.drawable.chokkanatha6};

    public ImageAdapter(Context context,String list1){
        this.context=context;
       String list =list1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        //imageView.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        System.out.println("position:"+position);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to put a `LinearLayout` in your `instatiateItem()` instead of only one `ImageView`

Set the `LinearLayout` orientation to vertical and add the `ImageView`, and below it add another `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation and in this inner layout add 5 (or how much you like) `ImageView` in which you will draw your thumbnails.

You should end up with something likes this:

```
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // this is your layout for the Item
        final LinearLayout outerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        outerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        outerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // this is your main picture
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        // add the picture to the layout
        outerLayout.addView(imageView);

        final LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // thumbnail for the previous image
        ImageView thumbnailBefore = new ImageView(context);
        thumbnailBefore.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        thumbnailBefore.setImageResource("enter your thumbnail for image with id position - 1");

        // thumbnail for the current image
        ImageView thumbnailThis = new ImageView(context);
        thumbnailThis.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        thumbnailThis.setImageResource("enter your thumbnail for image with id position");

        // thumbnail for the next image
        ImageView thumbnailAfter = new ImageView(context);
        thumbnailAfter.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        thumbnailAfter.setImageResource("enter your thumbnail for image with id position + 1");

        // add the thumbnails for the images to the inner layout (to appear below your main picture)
        innerLayout.addView(thumbnailBefore);
        innerLayout.addView(thumbnailThis);
        innerLayout.addView(thumbnailAfter);

        // add the inner layout to the whole layout
        outerLayout.addView(innerLayout);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(outerLayout, 0);

        return imageView;
    }
```

And depending on which image is displayed now, you should fill your inner `LinearLayout` with the pictures before and after it. (Watch out for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with positions of thumbnails)

Sorry for not supplying you with exact code, I am not at my computer right now.

**EDIT:** I posted code sample for displaying previous and next picture.
Also if you don't have the thumbnails of the picture, see this answer for more details [Make thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294235/5118375)

Comment: can u brief me once ur in front of system